# Home Footing Falling apart

Tags: concrete, repair, foundation, diy-vs-pro

My wife and I recently bought a house and noticed how poor the footing on the house looked. We’re wanting to repair it, but I do not have much experience with this stuff.

It seems to be some sort of cement plaster/stucco on a wire mesh.

Any ideas on what the material currently is, what I can do to repair it, and what I can do to prevent it from happening again?

It is a single level home with crawl space.

Any help is appreciated[image]

Comment: seems like you have crawl space access - looking there (or investigating pre-purchase general inspection images) might be useful

Comment: This is a better problem to have, than having footings falling apart.  This is just decorative parging falling apart.  Footings are what your concrete foundation walls sit on.

Comment: @crip659, make your comment an answer.  It is what the OP and others reading the question need to know.

Comment: @RMDman  I would rather have someone else who knows how to fix/repair the parging correctly answer.  They can also use my comment or parts of it if they want.  I only dapple a bit with concrete/cement/mortar, mainly just enough to make a mess.

Comment: @crip659,  even the most seasoned pros make a mess when dealing with this kind of stuff.  It's just messy.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, rest assured that the pictured material is non-structural. It's simply a coating for aesthetic purposes to cover your home's *foundation*. The *footing* isn't visible here; that is buried some distance below the ground.

The stuff might be referred to as foundation plaster, parging, or stucco. I suppose a mason would be able to tell you about the finer points of difference in each of those, but to many of us, it's all kind of the same thing.

My best guess would be that the material de-laminated from the foundation as a result of freeze-thaw cycles in the winter or possibly thermal expansion in the summer. These things just break down over time; this appears to be well-aged and its failure is probably not due to poor workmanship or maintenance.

As for repair: "fixing" this may be difficult due to the challenge of matching color and texture in cementitious work. Consider leaving it alone until you're ready to fully remove and replace it.

Careful prep work will be the key to getting a good life from a newly applied coating. The materials and tools are inexpensive, so spend some time online researching how to do the work and then take a swing at it!

Answer (score 1):

That's not the footing. That a foundation **stemwall** and what's "falling apart" is a **stucco coating** over the actual foundation wall. Perhaps even (is that a bit blue?) over foam insulation applied to the outside of the concrete foundation wall (which is a very good thing. The insulation, not the falling apart stucco.)

The footing should be well-buried, below whatever your local frostline depth is.